# Square of the number of ones

Tags: code-golf

I'm solving problem: in file "a.in" given the number N - length of the number consists of ones. Need to gets square of it, and put this in file "a.out". This is my shortest solution(150 bytes):

```
char s[1<<27];j;main(i,n){for(fscanf(fopen("a.in","r"),"%d",&n),i=n*=2;--i;j+=i<n/2?i:n-i,s[i-1]=48+j%10,j/=10);fprintf(fopen("a.out","w"),"%s\n",s);}
```

This is formated copy:

```
char s[1<<27];j;
main(i,n){
    for(fscanf(fopen("a.in","r"),"%d",&n),i=n*=2;--i;
        j+=i < n/2 ? i: n-i,
        s[i - 1] = 48 + j % 10,
        j /= 10
    );
    fprintf(fopen("a.out","w"),"%s\n",s);
}
```

The best solution of this problem has size 131 bytes, how?

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit slow, but it took me a long time just to get what the program should do. If the number is 3, you want to print 111*111, which is 12321. Right?

Comment: What's the source of this puzzle?

Comment: Why the restriction to such a few languages?

Answer (score 3):

without changing your logic, you can save 9 characters by using `fputs` (instead of `fprintf`).

```
fputs(s,fopen("a.out","w"));
```

you can also save one character by not doubling `n` at first step, thus removing divide by two:

```
...,i=n*2;--i;
j+=i<n?i:2*n-i
```

Comment: I need write breakline(\n), but fputs no do this.

Comment: fputs works nice, 140 bytes

Comment: `fputs` doesn't add a newline (unlike `puts`).

Answer (score 2):

You can save another character, by doing `j/=10` after `for` - `for(...)j/=10;`

My best so far, 145 characters:

```
char s[1<<27];j;
main(i,n){
    for(fscanf(fopen("a.in","r"),"%d",&n),s[i=n*2-1]=10;i;
        j+=i<n?i:n*2-i,
        s[--i]=48+j%10
    )j/=10;
    fputs(s,fopen("a.out","w"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### C, 104 chars

(Assuming ugoren's comment is correct)

```
main(n,k){fscanf(fopen("a.in","r"),"%d",&n);for(k=1;--n;k=k*10+1);fprintf(fopen("a.out","w"),"%d",k*k);}
```

Note that I needed to compile it with `-m32` on OSX to keep it from crashing.  Probably something to do with the implicit prototypes brought about by not including `stdio.h`.

Comment: N may be in range [1, 5*10^7]

Comment: @Maxim: then that should be part of the question.

Comment: 1. C's implicit prototype assume functions return `int`. When they return a pointer, and it's larger than `int`, things go bad. 2. You can avoid initializing `k` if you switch it with `n` (and run the program without parameters). Saves 4 characters (if you also move `fscanf` into `for`. Or you can initialize `k` with `fscanf`'s return value.

Answer (score 2):

### J, 17 characters

Invalid answer and not really of any use to the OP, but I was bored and this occupied a few minutes.

```
*:10#.1$~".1!:1[1
```

`1!:1[1` take input from the keyboard,

`1$~` creates a list of 1s of the length specified by the input,

`10#.` converts to a base 10 number,

`*:` squares it.

Answer (score 2):

### GolfScript 7

Another answer in an illegal language, for the same reason as [the one invoked by Gareth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6575/3527).

```cs
~1`*~.*
```

Explanation:

- takes a number as command line parameter
- `~` evaluates the number
- `` 1` `` pushes the `'1'` string on the stack
- `*` multiplies the character `'1'` by the number specified as input (results in a string)
- `~` evaluates the string of `1`s, thus storing the equivalent numeric value on the stack
- `.*` squares the existing value

In order to get the expected output, the program should be called like this:

```
 more a.in | ruby golfscript.rb program.gs > a.out # :-)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun a 'dc' solution. It read/writes from stdin/stdout, because of its limitations

```
$ dc -e '?0sn[lnA*1+sn1-d0<x]dsxxlnd*p' <<< 3
12321
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes (feedback welcome!)

```
1xV²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9@wIuzQpv9A2gAA)

Repeat '1' a number of times equal to the input (`x`), concatenate and e`V`aluate the result, and square it.

**Old solution:**

```
RŒBV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o6CSnsP///xsDAA)

As per @ugoren's explanation. Make a range from 1 to N, then bounce it (mirror except the last element) with `ŒB` and use `V` to concatenate the digits.

Comment: This is wrong for inputs larger than 9.

Comment: Just wondering, why are you answering a bunch of questions that were last active in 2012?

Comment: @Nit Thank you! I missed that but found another more literal solution in the same amount of bytes. This one should work for larger inputs!

Comment: @JoKing Just trying to practice, and I figure might as well contribute to the site where other people can see. I'm just choosing questions I think that I can answer without considering the date. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 55 bytes

Just do an invalid answer in case file manipulation doesn't work.

```
Fn.new{|x|Num.fromString("1"*Num.fromString(x)).pow(2)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkFaal6xgq/DfLU8vL7W8uqaixq80Vy@tKD83uKQoMy9dQ8lQSQtNqEJTU68gv1zDSLP2f3BlcUlqrl55UWZJqgbIML3kxJwcDSVTJU3N/wA)

### Explanation

Takes input as string:

```
Fn.new{|x|                                            } // New anonymous function
                             Num.fromString(x)          // Convert input into a number
          Num.fromString("1"*                 )         // Evaluate 1 with that number times
                                               .pow(2)  // Square the resulting value
```

Answer (score 0):

### C#, 172 chars

```
namespace System{class P{static void Main(){var b=Numerics.BigInteger.Parse(new String('1',int.Parse(IO.File.ReadAllText("a.in"))));IO.File.WriteAllText("a.out",b*b+"");}}}
```

Best I could do with a language with big integers.  Unless you're willing to add Python to the language list...

Answer (score 0):

**Java, 198 chars**

Saw you mention Java, thought I'd give it a try. This is the best I can get using the standard runtime:

```
import java.io.*;enum F{F;System s;{try{s.setOut(new PrintStream("a.out"));s.out.print((int)Math.pow(1/(9/Math.pow(10,new java.util.Scanner(new File("a.in")).nextInt())),2));}catch(Exception e){}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### bash: 69 chars:

```
w=$(for i in $(seq 1 `<a.in`)
do
echo -n 1
done)
echo $((w**2))>a.out
```

a.out - really? :)

The only problem: invalid language.

Answer (score 0):

## K, 13

Another invalid answer but what the hell.

```
{a*a:.:x#"1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-hr`, 5 bytes

```
1⅍*ℤ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///f8FFrr9ajliWHNv3/b/JfN6MIAA)

Another illegal answer, but hey, as far as I know, there ain't any CGCC jail y'all can throw me into.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Outputs a digit array.

```
ì1 ì²
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=7DEg7LI&input=OA)

Answer (score -1):

## C, 130 chars

```
char s[1<<27];main(i,n,j){for(read(open("a.in",0),s),n=atoi(s);j=j/10+n-abs(n-i);s[n*2-++i]=48+j%10);fputs(s,fopen("a.out","w"));}
```

Comment: Since you are actually willing to make the effort, would you please clarify your question? 3 people asked about some fine points; and got no answer. Also, you did some more clarifications in comments; they belong in the question itself.